# Job website use case diagrams

Tags: uml, diagram, jobs, use-case

Here is my Job website use cases diagram. I do not know if what I did is correct or not.
Any help?
[image: jobwebsite]

### Edit 1

Here is the modified version of the online job portal system:
[image: jobportalsystem]

this system contains two complex use cases: "Account Management" and "Job Application".
Here is the diagram for Account Management:
[image: accountmanagement]

and the diagram for Job Application:
[image: jobapplication]

I need your opinions.

Comment: +1. A good piece of work for a beginner, but better move your newer diagrams in the "edit 1" chapter here, instead of own answer. Waiting for "Edit 2"...

Comment: I hope this is what you wanted. I have to delete my answer? 
I'm trying to improve my diagram taking into account your remarks. As soon as I finish, I will share my new version to benefit your comments. Really, thank you for your advice.

Comment: No, I didn't want you to delete anything, only to put everything in the question, so our polylogue will be more understandable for later readers. Many people start to do the use cases as you did, and they need some steps to change they point of view. BTW, you can rollback by clicking on the "edited X mins ago" line below the post

Comment: I have not assimilated well what do you mean by edit chapter: edit my description to the issue or amend the French version of the diagram in an English version? I want my question to be as comprehensible as possible to help those who have the same problem as me.

Comment: I only wanted to see as diagrams in your questions developed step after step. But you needn't keep to my point of view. It is your question after all.

Comment: @Gangnus if it's possible you could edit my post as you like to be more understandable.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46662/discussion-between-gangnus-and-marie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not bad, but there are some problems.

- Job Application is a process and is a Use Case. But Account (of anybody) is NOT an action or a process. It is an inner term in your application. It should appear at first in your component diagram, or even later.
- "extend" means that the pointed subject is a variation of the pointing one. You obviously misuse it.
- Account management is a subsystem - rectangle that is a part of the large one and contains the appropriate use cases. If drawing that is inconvenient, use for (sub)systems small rectangles and containment dependencies (with cross in circle on the side of container) and connect them to Use Cases by simple connectors. Of course, you needn't put dialogues with all subsystems on the same diagram.
- Maintaining of website is not connected to any practical use case really. It is separate admin task. Or you mean by it something else? Then change the name.
- You have use cases not connected to any actor. It is an error.
- Login is not part of job application. View vacancies are not variation of it, too. Favorite vacancies ARE extension of view vacancies.
- Please, try to minimize the use of "include" and "extend" in Use Case Diag. In 90% cases people use them, when they incorrectly are describing structure information on the Use Case diag. Here you write only Who will do What to Whom, and maybe a bit structure these Whos and Whoms into organizations and subsystems. Notice, you can describe structure ABOVE use case, not BELOW it!

Small details:

- you could consider divide moderator from administrator.
- edit your connections lines - they are strangled more than necessary.

(And thank you very much for translation - my French is too miserable to manage the modelling)

A bit more on @pid answer.

I am afraid, I can't agree with ignoring the pure human operations. On the contrary. Put them here, only their use cases will connect not actor-(sub)system, but actor-actor. And seeing them is very good for better planning the system as a whole. And ignoring them it is impossible to create a system good for user. The IT system is an integral component of the larger system, and we are creating the larger one really, with planning the support, processes, exchange of info, divisions and dependencies.

Comment: Since Account (of anybody) is not an action or a process, I have to remove it from the use case diagram?

Comment: All of them. They are classes. Or components consisting of some classes, if they are more complicated. But they are not Actions or Processes. They can't be even Subsystems.

Comment: But Account management could be a subsystem. Account registering, or register account could be use case. Same for delete or edit account

Comment: I agree with the larger system but Marie is trying to grasp the basics. From tutoring experience I can tell you it's better if she thinks about the system as a program that she will have to design and implement with clear boundaries. Writing the non-implementation features of the system in natural language helps her understanding that difference. But it's true and I agree with you that a system also has human labor workflows and those are an integral part of it.

Comment: @pid I, on the other side, have problems with programmers who are blind to anything out of IT system border. And often it is impossible to make them think out of these borders. As a result, the result system is blind to the real needs of the user. So we have that sad picture of user-hating software.

Comment: @pid maybe, it is better to start to study the problem from actions that are out of the system, and to create firstly the diagram, that considers IT system as merely one of many blocks.

Comment: I have to admit that I come from the *other side* (designer) and requirements/constraints are handed to me. I don't often get a look to the grand context of IT systems, that's mostly done by managers of my organization. So I *must* agree with your broader view and thank you for sharing it with me!

Comment: At your service :-). I had come from the algorithms myself, but I had to model some large systems, and define the requirements with client.

Comment: @Gangnus: I edited my early answer with bold text, so you can see that we are merely agreeing on those points but the exposition was different.

Comment: @Gangnus "You have use cases not connected to any actor. It is an error." For example?

Comment: @Marie Add vacancies, delete account, upload CV... They are normal use cases

Comment: For example, "delete account" extend "account management". "job seeker account" include "account management" and "job seeker account" is related to Job Seeker actor.This is not sufficient to tell "delete account" is related to Job Seeker actor? I Know, I will discard "job seeker account". But for now, I want to understand why "delete account" is considered as not related to any actor?

Comment: Sorry, but all your "extend" are not correct. Extend means that the second use case is a variant of the first one. It is not so in all your "extend" cases.

Comment: If "delete account" is not a variant of "account management", what is the relation between these use cases? I mean by "extend" an optional behavior. So, a job seeker may or may not delete his account.

Comment: Account management is one of "subjects", i.e., subsystems. Its use cases will be connected to it AND to some actor. Look comment 3 here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46692/discussion-between-marie-and-gangnus)

Answer (score 1):

You are completely missing the system's boundaries (the center box with "System" labeled above).

On a conceptual level it is very important to understand what your system's boundaries are, and what is just *human driven* collateral/corollary labor. Keep those outside the boundary (on paper don't even draw a use case for it, **in your mind understand it's part of the system but not something you implement in code**, it will be documentation, training or laws) but keep it in the diagram on a sidebar.

That sidebar (the *at latere natural language semantic substrate*) should be written in simple words and sentences. If you can't do it, you should try to better understand the domain, simplify the diagram and split it in many diagrams.

Split it down into 3 or 4 different diagrams, each of which should be focused on those use cases which are cohesive. Use different diagrams for un-related use cases and different facets of the system.
Find the right cut between complexity and simplicity, I suspect you're a bit overdoing it with the extends.

Remember: UML diagrams are surgical tools, use them as focused as possible. More is not better, it is only confusing or dispersing.

Finally, write down actual scenarios for the more complex use cases (those with many extensions). You'll see how difficult it will be to take into account all extension points. This will be a good indication on how complex the system is going to be.

The more you can simplify in this early stage the better for later design and implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account your remarks, here is the modified version of my diagram. I have two complex use cases to develop "Account Management" and "Postulation." But before taking this step, I wanted to know if the attached diagram is correct or there are some improvements to be introduced?
[image: jobusecasediagram]

Comment: Without any doubts. You could put it here in English. I do write my diagrams in Czech here. The language of SO is English, like it or blast it.

Comment: OK @ Gangnus. I'll try to produce an  English clean version. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified version of the online job portal system:
[image: jobportalsystem]

this system contains two complex use cases: "Account Management" and "Job Application".
Here is the diagram for Account Management:
[image: accountmanagement]

and the diagram for Job Application:
[image: jobapplication]

I need your opinions.

Comment: I know this is a bit [finicky](https://www.google.com/search?q=finicky) but you really need to draw every time the system boundaries as a rectangle around the use cases.

Comment: @pid you can also use "containment" connections and small rectangles for system and subsystems.